# How to manage files/directories discovery and use in c++ on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

I'm stuck in terms of solutions for such thing.

```
ifstream infile;  
string STRING = "";  
string cdd = "PATH HERE";  
infile.open(cdd);  
while (!infile.eof())  
{  
getline(infile, STRING);  
}
```

This is what I achieve through fstream library, and I find it fine, now the problem comes when I need to scan the directory(for files and directories) where the .exe is placed and obtain a list which I can iterate to find directories/files and which I use to pass the path string to cdd. I found different libraries such as , and , but because of the different types used in each library, I can't figure out how to nest functionalities that I need. If there is no way to nest such functionalities, someone can point to a 1 file only library that achieve such needed tasks?

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler supports C++17 and you can/want to use it you can use [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) which is part of C++17.